# I lost ssh connection to my instance CSR 1000v AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cisco

I erased the configuration of my `CSR 1000v` bu using the CLI command `wr erase` and there `reload`. After that, I lost the `SSH` connection. I was not able to connect to the instance even though it has a public IP and DNS.
It always asks me a password after running `SSH` command to connect.

`ec2-user@ec2-34-211-24-85.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com's password:`

Comment: I'm not a cisco guy, but when I google the `wr erase` command, it always comes up in connection with resetting something to the factory default. If you reset your appliance, maybe the default/initial password is the solution for you.

Comment: @Maurice yes, that was my guess too. it deletes literally everything which was saved in `NVRAM`  including the ssh authentification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that deleting `NVRAM` using `we erase` and reloading `reload` for CSR routers in AWS, will completely delete all the router's configuration including the ssh key which is attached to the router during the configuration.